# Cannot compile git on OpenBSD

Tags: compiling, git, make, openbsd

I'm trying to install git on a college server, just for my user, but for some reason I can't compile it. I tried the latest version on github, as well as a couple random older versions from both github and kernel.org

Running `make configure` results in [this](https://pastebin.com/ENwPaM3n)

I was able to compile zsh from source without any issues, so at least `make` seems to work correctly

Output of `uname -a`:

```
OpenBSD [redacted host name] 6.0 GENERIC.MP#2319 amd64
```

`gcc -v`:

```
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/amd64-unknown-openbsd6.0/4.2.1/specs
Target: amd64-unknown-openbsd6.0
Configured with: OpenBSD/amd64 system compiler
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 20070719
```

EDIT: After some time of trying to get git to work, I give up (at least for now). I'm going to ask the admins to install git, but in the meantime I'll have to use workarounds, like downloading zip files from GitHub, instead of cloning.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is not universal.

The `Makefile` that you are using is specific to the GNU `make` program.  You are using OpenBSD's `make` program, derived from Adam de Boor's `pmake`.  They have quite different syntaxes.

If you build git from the OpenBSD ports tree in `/usr/ports/devel/git`, you'll find that this, and other stuff, has all been worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

From looking the errors in your question, it seems steps are missing, liking doing the `autoconf` or the actual `configure`. (e.g. the compiler is complaining of missing variables).

Looking at the official git github page, [Compiling git](https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/8671036)

The actual steps to compile `git`, are:

```
autoconf
./configure
make && make install
```

I advise there are not generic one-fit-all procedures to compile software from source, whilst there are some common procedures, so it is always advised to look for specific instructions how to build a particular package.

PS. `autoconf` creates the `./configure` file.

Comment: It seems like I don't have `autoconf` installed, and there is no `./configure` in `git-2.21.0` source.

Comment: You can always try to compile autoconf... It is the one responsible for creating the `./configure` file. Would not be easier to ask helpdesk for the git command?

Comment: I would suggest asking the sysadmin to install a newer version of `git` and to upgrade the OpenBSD installation in the process.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed, considering 6.4 was released October....

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried compiling autoconf from source (I also had to compile m4, since it was out of date), but it didn't work. I'm going to try using the ports tree JdeBP mentions and see what I can do. Worst case scenario I'll ask the admins if they would install git for me. They apparently installed tmux, so who knows

Comment: I thought of ports, but decided to not advise it as 1) it might not be installed 2) You need root access to use it directly. But if you are able to copy from there, it might be worth a try.